# How to dual-boot Ubuntu and Android on Lenovo s10-3t?

Tags: dual-boot, android, ideapad

I have a problem with installing Android on Ubuntu. I have already 12.04 installed on Ideapad Lenovo s10-3t but I didn't leave an empty partition for Android.

Is it possible to separate it now or do I have to reboot Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You can change partitions sizesusing GParted for example. This program is in Ubuntu Software Center. After you succeded with creating partition for Android, you can install it. However be aware that changing partition size can lead to some problems when made wrong.